# Safely edit the Database with multiple threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I am trying to learn **multi-threading in java**.
Suppose I have a very big application with 100 running threads trying to execute a synchronized method which inserts a row in database.

As, the method is synchronized so only one thread will get the lock for that method and rest 99 will wait.

Only 1 thread is able to edit the Database and rest will be waiting. It seems a slow process. As all the threads will be editing the DB one by one. Is there any other way or concept to safely edit the database in a faster way?

Comment: Too broad, but in general you should only synchronize if your own program requires it, and let the database do its own thing.  Most databases these days are multi-threaded and concurrent, you should let them handle their data themselves.  (Although it might be reasonable to limit the database requests to some number less than 100, but you should measure performance first.)

Comment: Hi @markspace, you're saying that modern databases like MySQL, Oracle are already multi-threaded and concurrent. I don't have to use synchronized methods to change my DB?

Comment: @Anonymous One of the main jobs of a database engine is to manage concurrent access. Some databases such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) use [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) as the technique to provide consistent concurrent access. Your Java code only needs to address concurrency issues within your Java app, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

i will recommend u to read about isolation level in transaction to handle some cases in concurrent application https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems), sometimes is handles by default.
if for isntance u only adding new rows in table u shouldn't care about it and remove synchronized

Comment: I'll second this.  Transaction and isolation are typically used in client (application) code to solve "concurrency" problems.  (I mean "concurrency" here in the broadest way possible, not just multi-threading.)  OTOH your code might require synchronization regardless, but typically you only worry about your code itself, the database already has its own synchronization and you don't have to duplicate that.